# Mass action law and conservation of mass

Tags: reaction-mechanism, kinetics

I am starting to learn about the use of mass action law in chemistry. I am doing some exercises to practice. In particular, I am considering the reaction
$$2 X \underset{3}{\stackrel{4}{\rightleftharpoons}} Y.$$ By mass action law I have obtained the following system of ODE's
$$ \left\{
 \begin{array}{ l }
    \frac{d}{dt}x(t)=-8x^2+6y\\
    \frac{d}{dt}y(t)=4x^2-3y,
 \end{array}\label{SEDO} \right.$$

where I have used this result.
[image]

I am wondering if it is usual that the amount $x(t)+y(t)$ is not conservated.

Comment: That should be obvious from the reaction's equation...

Comment: I am a Math student, so I don't know too much about chemistry. Do you mean that the equations are wrong?

Comment: If you make one Y from two X than why would you expect to still have two?

Comment: There is law of mass conservation, there is no law of molar amount conservation. 1 mol of Y can be formed from 2 mol of X with the same mass.

Comment: Please MathJax the screenshots

Comment: Where does the screenshot come from?

Comment: What is $x$ ? What is $y$ ? What is the "system of ODE" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rate laws that you show don't give an identity to $x$ or $y$. I am going to assume they are moles, even though it is uncommon to show rate laws as a function of moles. The time evolution of the amount of substance of both species can be written as
\begin{align}
  \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t} &=
  -8x^2 + 6y = (-2) (4x^2 - 3y) \tag{1} = -2r_1\\
  \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t} &=
  4x^2 - 3y = (+1) (4x^2 - 3y) = r_1 \tag{2}
\end{align}
where we defined $r_1 := 4x^2 - 3y$. Thus:

1. It is clear that $x(t) + y(t)$ is not a conserved quantity. This is because for every $2$ moles disappeared of $x$, you get only $1$ mol of $y$. But the quantity $x(t)+2y(t)$ is conserved, by using Eqs. (1-2)
   \begin{align}
     x + 2y &= \text{constant} \\
     \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t} + 2\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t} &= 0 \\
     (-2r_1) + 2(r_1) &= 0 \rightarrow 0=0 \tag{3}
   \end{align}
2. The mass for a **chemical** reaction is conserved, but this quantity is not $x(t) + y(t)$ rather it is $M_x x(t) + M_yy(t)$, where $M$'s are the molar masses of the compounds. Again, by Eqs. (1-2)
   \begin{align}
     \require{cancel}
     M_xx + M_yy &= \text{constant} \\
     M_x\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t} + M_y\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t} &= 0 \\
     (-2M_x)r_1 + (M_y)r_1 &= 0 \rightarrow -2M_x + M_y = 0 \tag{4} \\
   \end{align}
   Eq. (4) is always satisfied. To give an example that is similar to your chemical reaction, we can illustrate the decomposition of nitrogen dioxide in the gas phase
   $$ \ce{2NO2(g) \rightleftharpoons N2O4(g)} \tag{5} $$
   And this chemical equation satisfies
   \begin{align}
     -2M_\ce{NO2} + M_\ce{N2O4} &= 0 \\
     (-2) \left(\pu{46.01 \frac{g}{mol}}\right) +
     \left(\pu{92.02 \frac{g}{mol}}\right) &= 0 \\
     (-92.02 + 92.02) \; \pu{\frac{g}{mol}} &= 0 \rightarrow 0=0 \tag{6}
   \end{align}

To generalize, for a general chemical reaction that comprises $m$ species, we always have
$$ \boxed{\sum_{j = 1}^m \nu_j M_{j} = 0} \tag{7} $$
So, if you solve a system that has at time $t$ an amount of moles of $x_1(t)$, $x_2(t)$, ..., $x_m(t)$, then $M_1x_1(t) + M_2x_2(t) + \dots + M_m x_m(t)$ is constant. It is a good check to see if the code is satisfying the mass balance by calculating this quantity and viewing that it does not deviate, apart from the absolute/relative errors that you specify.

Comment: Thank you! Now is completely clear for me!